# Secure files from direct access

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

I have hosted a site, the documents suggest to put files under folder `public_html`.
I have three files `index.php`(view page), `common.js`, and `result.php(php)` in root folder. On clicking a button in `index.php`(view) file will trigger an ajax function to `result.php`.

The problem is everyone can access the `result.php` directly...

I trying to make folder structure, that all php files(`result.php`) are in folder behind root. So it will not accessed directly from browser using rewrite rule or anything else.

Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: try to add files before **public_html/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a file only acccessible via ajax you can use:

```
public static function isAjax() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

It returns true or false. Basically if it returns true then let the user carry on otherwise stop them.

Word of caution: Not all JS libraries/frameworks actually set this header but most do (JQuery, Mootools etc) and not all versions so make sure you have the latest version of a library/framework before you use this.

Plus if the user spoofs your headers then there is no real way to stop them.

I tend to use this as a precursor for stopping AJAX pages from being visible publicly. I also use parameter integrity checking and a random hash stored in session (CSRF type thing) to check if the user is legitamately accessing an AJAX page.

Comment: This does not guarantee the request was made via XMLHttpRequest. It only guarantees that the client sent some headers which means nothing if he is trying to spoof the request.

Comment: @Vatev So what if the user spoofs the headers, CSRF is another topic not covered by this question. This header is sent by most frameworks and what not now-a-days as such if this header is set is the first step to understanding wether or not the user entered the page through a browser or not. As such it fullfills the OPs question. If he wants fool proof guard then he should read up on CSRF.

Comment: 'The problem is everyone can access the result.php directly' - your solution does not solve this problem, and to make it worse it looks like it does. Someone might think it works and use it for something that is suppose to be secure.

Comment: @Vatev Ha the users question has been changed to mean something else. The title and the content original read along the lines of: "Secure php files from accessed directly from browser"

Answer (score 1):

You can't protect it by moving it around, because there is no way to distinguish if a request to `result.php` was triggered by a legitimate AJAX call from `index.php` except for a session (or some other type of token).
You need to use a php session (or something equivalent) to:

1. Store what the use has access to (in index.php).
2. Check if he has access to it in (result.php)

Comment: What if he has no sessions? What if there is no distinguishation between users, he wants the page public for all users except for those accessing through the browser. This will not solve any of his problems...

Comment: @Sammaye and Vatev: I have no session, no distinguish  between users, I wants the page public for all users except ajax php file can't access directly from browser...

Comment: In that case use @Sammaye's answer and be warned that it only works if the client plays by the rules.

Comment: If I use session, client unfair activities can be stopped? Is it better to use a session here?

Comment: @JustinJohn No. Since the AJAX call will be static in the HTML (so no way to really dynamically change its binding unless you make a uber complex script to do it) the only real way is just to accept users will be able to enter AJAX pages if they spoof headers. Sometimes there are just some things you still cannot stop...

Comment: @JustinJohn If the question about 'the way people are allowed to access the script' then Sammaye's answer is probably the best you can get. If the question is about 'which people are allowed to access the script' then you have to use sessions.

Comment: Thanks Vatev for your help, I think I will go with sammaye's solution as well as your solution integrated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a file accessible via ajax and then not accessible via the correct browser requests, as the Ajax call is doing the same behaviour a web-browser could.